# Checkboxes Inside A File Tree

Tags: java, tapestry

So the issue is that I'm getting a runtime error about checkboxes generated inside a file tree needing to be inside a form element. Thing is, it is inside a form element but the form element is wrapped around the tree like so:

```
<t:Form t:id="form>
  <t:Tree t:id="tree" model="model" node="node">
    <p:label>
      ${node.label}
      <t:Checkbox value="checkboxNode.selected" />
    </p:label>
  </t:Tree>
</t:Form>
```

The root level of nodes generate the checkboxes without issue. However, when I select the plus to expand the tree branch it throws the error for the branch checkboxes. This goes away if I refresh the page and it remembers which branches are expanded. If I go to expand more, then it throws the error again. The same thing happens if I minimize a branch and then expand it again.

I suspect this has to do with how expanding the tree generates its fields using an AJAX call and it not being able to detect the form wrapped on the outside. Two possible work around I've thought of are:

1. Default the nodes as expanded and disable the minimizing functionality. I lose out on one of the interaction and organization advantages of a file tree doing this though.
2. Put a form inside the label. This creates a lot of unnecessary extra forms though and I'm not quite sure how to consolidate this into the end goal of creating a list of groups to send emails out to based on the selected labels.

Anyone here have any insight about a better work around for this issue or maybe a way to tell the generated checkboxes to recognize the outer form without needing to reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a different route. The issue I ran into with the checkboxes that was a deal breaker was I couldn't think of a way to tell the booleans on the server side to update based on the client side's checkboxes.

The reason for that was that the booleans were generated based on need instead of being a fixed set on the Java side of the page. Tried a work around by linking unique IDs to the booleans on the server side, but even then I could not determine a way to associate those IDs to the checkboxes on the client side.

So instead I went with eventlinks, which can take a context. I just passed in the generated tree node IDs as a context, which could search for the node in the eventlink and be added to a "selected" list on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As [JavaDoc for the `Tree` component](https://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Tree.html) states:

> Tree is *not* a form control component...

Have a look at the source code of `AjaxFormLoop` and the way it handles AJAX form updates, I believe you need to build a custom component for your needs.